# Is address line 1 + address line 2 an anti-pattern?

Tags: forms, addresses, anti-patterns

The typical address block on a form contains two fields for address:

```
Address
-------------------------------
|                             |
-------------------------------

Address Line 2
-------------------------------
|                             |
-------------------------------

City
-------------------------------
|                             |
-------------------------------

State
-------------------------------
|                             |
-------------------------------

ZIP
-------------------------------
|                             |
-------------------------------
```

Are two lines for the address really necessary? I've never personally had a use for the second line and, at best, it's an empty field, and, at worst, it screws up my browser's form auto-fill settings. I did an informal office survey and heard the same from others--that they've never needed it.

Are there real world scenarios where it's needed?

I understand that it's often seen as an apartment field, but even that can be written as one line (and something I've done in the past):

> 1234 5th Avenue North, Apt 45

Is this just an old habit/anti-pattern that we should consider breaking?

Comment: UK addresses use the Address line 2 frequently

Comment: It's common to have two lines outside of US. If a good amount of users are from out of states then you may want to consider keeping it. Some ideas to make the line 2 more user-friendly: http://baymard.com/blog/address-line-2

Comment: @Poyi that's a really good link! Great info!

Comment: City/State/ZIP also constitute an anti-pattern in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Crissov Interesting! please elaborate!

Comment: It’s US-centric. In many countries, at least one of these is either non-existant, meaningless or redundant. Also, the order as shown is not sequential.

Comment: I live in Argentina and I've never see something like "adress line 2", not even in international sites where I've shopped.

Comment: @Crissov The idea of city / state / zip is to have a concise and even machine-readable code which is also spelled out for humans. Most people do not have all the zip codes memorized, but can easily recall the name of a town. Since it serves a purpose it is not an anti-pattern. What is an issue is that the zip should be entered *first*, then the town displayed, and the user merely confirms that they got it right. We have enshrined the wrong order in practice, which is indeed stupid.

Answer (score 5):

### Keep it for business addresses

In business contexts it is often used for 'Attn:' lines or department names. In large metro areas, it is also commonly used for building ID, eg 'West Tower'. You could mask it until business address is checked. Unfortunately, people don't always catch that requirement.

In the end, you have to ask yourself what's more likely to disturb the user. This input is a standard. Some people need it to properly enter their address. Some use it out of habit for their apt number or other qualifier. Lots of people skip it. And they're used to that.

### Who broke your auto-fill?

I'm not sure why it would mess up auto-fill. If the field is properly identified in the mark-up, auto-fill should see it accurately. If you use it your data fills, if not it gets skipped.

Answer (score 5):

Two address lines are necessary. A common use for the second line is to bring attention to a specific location or sub-address within a large business park or manufacturing facility. It is also commonly used when shipping internationally and the address is very lengthy.

**Example #1 (Attention to location inside shipyard):**

```
Block X, Office Number 0-12, 2nd Floor, Karma Height,
Landmark: Next to Goa Shipyard / above Hero Honda showroom,
Vaddem, Vasco Da Gamma, Goa-403804
```

**Example #2 (A lengthy international address):**

```
Remi Biz Court, F wing Office No.501,
5th Floor Shah Indl. Est., Veera Desai Road,
Andheri west, Mumbai 400 058
```

Comment: Do those officially have to be two lines, or is that merely how they are printed?

Comment: @DA01 It doesn't really matter, does it? If people are used to writing it on two lines, you'll just create a hurdle by trying to help them be more efficient. I also think it helps to break up long strings of essentially random info -- two lines may actually help with comprehension and recall in the end.

Comment: @plainclothes I don't entirely disagree, but I'm not entirely convinced, either. Look at the article Poyi links too. I think my  main hang-up is that we're essentially separating an arbitrary data field into two arbitrary data fields. Granted, addresses are arbitrary, but I'm not convinced two fields is making that easier to input for the user.

Comment: @DA01 in this case, the arbitrariness didn't start with web forms it started with the international postal trade. Post masters like things formatted in a certain way, and this is one of those preferences. The line 1 + line 2 form standard is just giving users what they already expect.

Comment: I have a better idea: What if everyone got their own bitly link that postal databases expanded to wherever they happen to live at the moment? I'm kind of kidding, but wouldn't that be awesome?

Comment: @plainclothes that's an interesting requirement though. Because the *post office* wants it a certain way, we're asking you, the user, to accommodate. Not that that is an invalid reason, but typically we don't like forcing users to do the formatting required by 3rd parties. I'm also not convinced the postal system needs 1 2 or 3 lines. As this is a form, odds are it will be mechanically printed on the label and OCR will pick it up. Whether it's one line or two lines seems like an antiquated issue these days.

Comment: (I am, of course, way over thinking this. Not trying to make an argument! I just find it an interesting topic I had never thought about before...)

Comment: @DA01 I'm glad you mentioned that you're 'over thinking' :-)  I agree with your over-analysis: the USPS actually can accommodate and process the majority of addresses using 1 "delivery address line" (ref: USPS pub #28). However, people in the US addressed envelopes using 2 lines for this info, way prior to modern computers. Once db storage wasn't so precious that we had to literally conserve every byte, computer screens and forms accommodated users (and usability/readability) by providing 2 lines for the street address.  Beware the Anti-Pattern "I've never seen it, so it must not be needed"

Comment: @plainclothes Here is an idea: do away with all physical mail and just send everything by the web. Oh, here's my new phone case, gotta go.

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory for ecommerce (more details needed for delivering goods) but you can skip it for a lot of other subscription as you may only want demographical infos on your DB.

Comment: Why is it mandatory?

Comment: Users often add more infos to be sure to receive their purchases. I mean it's wildly encouraged to keep it :)

Comment: And sometimes it's related to the solution that the merchant will use to print the address on the package.

Comment: Right, but neither of those seem UX-friendly. There's no reason (that I can see) that an address can't be on one line vs. 2. The article that Poyi links to above is actually pretty good...it talks about how it adds confusion more than helps.